# Python Error (TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable)

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a problem with python when creating functions with images here is the code:
This usually happens when creating classes with a function I want to run that displays an image to the screen.

```
import pygame

white = (255,255,255)
width,height = 800,500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = pygame.image.load("graphics/player/player.png")
    def player(self):
        win.blit(self.player, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
    
    
game = Game()

def functions():
    game.player()

def loop():
    flag = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while flag:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                flag = False
                pygame.quit()

        functions()
        pygame.display.update()


loop()
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:", line 35, in <module>
    loop()
  File "C:", line 32, in loop
    functions()
  File "C:", line 19, in functions
    game.player()
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = pygame.image.load("graphics/player/player.png")
    def player(self):
        win.blit(self.player, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
```

`__init__()` defines an attribute named `self.player`.

There is also a class instance method named `player`.

You can't do that.  Pick a different name for one of them.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have 15 reputation but this is the right answer.